# Jersey "could not find suitable constructor" for subresource

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

This jax-rs api was working fine with CXF, but need to move to Jersey and now encounter this issue.

I have a root "CasesResource" and a subresource "CaseResource" (eg. "/cases/1234abc"). The subresource "CaseResource" is constructed with parameters passed in by the CaseResource. Only the CasesResource is added in the Application class's getClasses method.

```
@Path("cases")
public class CasesResource extends ConfigurationDepenentResource
{ 
    
    public CasesResource()
    {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getList(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("sort") @Encoded String sort)
    {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public CaseInfoResource upload(...) 
    {
        ...
    }

    @Path("{id}")
    public CaseResource getCaseResource(@PathParam("id") final String caseId, @Context HttpServletRequest req)
    {
        ...
        return new CaseResource(caseId, getConfigurationManager());
    }
}
```

and here's the subresource

```
@Path("/cases/{id}")
public class CaseResource
{
    private final String id;
    private final AbstractWebConfigurationManager configurationManager;

    public CaseResource(String id, AbstractWebConfigurationManager configurationManager)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.configurationManager = configurationManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as I was posting so I thought I might as well post it with the answer. The problem was the @Path annotation on the subresource class. Once that was removed, it worked as expected. I guess CXF didn't care as long as the classes weren't added in getClasses() but Jersey does.